# How to remove silencing errors is descouraged error from magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, xpath, magento2, phpcs

I have written code for SSO in magento 2.3 and for handling response from differnt IDPs like okta, keycloak I have done following code:

```
 if(!(@$xpath->query('/saml2p:Response',$xml))) {

            $status = SAML2Utilities::xpQuery($xml, './samlp:Status/samlp:StatusCode');   
}
        else{

           $status = SAML2Utilities::xpQuery($xml, './saml2p:Status/saml2p:StatusCode');   
}
```

My code is working fine, I can login through different IDPs, but when I checked php coding standard for magento 2 I am getting following error: 
 'Silencing errors is discouraged; found: @$xpath->query... '
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP errors can be silenced by using `@` operator. On your code you have:

```
if(!(@$xpath->query('/saml2p:Response',$xml))) {
```

so you have a `@` before `$xpath->query`. If you remove `@` the error will not be displayed when you will check for coding standards.

For more information regarding hiding errors you can check the [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

**UPDATE:**

Removing `@` may cause problems as if an error happens it will stop code execution. You either need to handle the errors with a try catch or make check such as check if variable is null, empty etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Error does disappear if I remove @, but plugin stops working because error stops the flow, how to resolve that?

Comment: You need to handle errors manually. You can wrap it in a try catch, check if `$xpath` is not null etc.